# UISplitViewController's master view is exceeding its visible bounds

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm having a weird issue with UISplitViewController's Master view controller on iOS 14. Its view somehow exceeds the bounds of visible view. Here are the screenshots from :
(1. Simulator, 2. ViewDebugger, 3. ViewDebugger with "Show Clipped Views" enabled)

P.S: The extra amount seems to be precisely 100 points (There's a constraint for that)

P.S 2: Disabling "presentMasterWithGesture" which adds 100 points to leading edge didn't help

[image: Simulator Screenshot]

[image: View Debugger Screenshot]

[image: ViewDebugger with "Show Clipped Views" enabled screenshot]

Any idea about the root cause is really appreciated.

Comment: Hi there! I'm suffering from the same effect. It's like the wrapper view is pushed 100 points towards the left. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I cannot remember correctly as this is for a few years ago, but if I recall correctly, I had to disable some parameter in the inspector view in the storyboard. I know it's late but Let me know if you haven't fixed it yet.